# Closure of COM ports at application termination

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, windows-10, com-port

I am writing a GUI application that runs on Windows 10 and opens COM ports (at least 4).

There is no explicit closing of the COM ports in the application.
My understanding is that Windows OS will close (unlock) the COM ports as part of terminating the application.

1. What happens to the COM ports when the application closes?
2. Should the COM ports be closed, by the application, before the application exits?
   (For example, in the application's "close" method.)

Our target PC (laptop) sometimes has issues communicating through the COM ports and the PC must be rebooted.  Communications is fine after the reboot.

**Background:**
GUI application written in C++ using MFC.
IDE is Visual Studio 2017
Application runs on Windows 10 (and windows 7).
COM ports are opened using Windows API.

Comment: For any resource which mingt need to be released (like serial ports) why don't you use [RAII](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization)?

Comment: For COM ports it is also a good idea to `PurgeComm` before `CloseHandle`.

Comment: I'm no com port expert. Looked online, and it appears a com port is opened with OpenFile(). At process termination, Windows should close the file. However, it may not purge/flush the file. I say it is better practice for the developer to control this. The place in MFC to clear up resources like this is in the overridden CWinApp::ExitInstance() before calling the baseclass version. I'd probably create objects to manage com port lifetime so I know that the destructor closes them. You may find that you could use CFile or a derived version for this.